# Populate another input field value after first input value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two scripts....

**1. HTML Part :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 

<script>

function loaddata()
{

var email=document.getElementById( "email" );
var email1 =  $(email).val();
if(email1)
{
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'form-inputs.php',
        data: {
        user_email:email1,
        },
        success: function (response) {

        // We get the element having id of display_info and put the response inside it
        $( '#display_info' ).html(response);

        }
       });

    }

else
{
$( '#display_info' ).value("Please Enter Some Words");
}

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input name="email" id="email"  onkeyup="loaddata();" required/>

<br><br>
<input name="udf1" id="udf1"  readonly="readonly"/>

<br>
 <div id="display_info" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. form-inputs.php :**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);
##############################

if( isset( $_POST['user_email'] ) ){

$emailfetch=$_POST['user_email'];

$sqlraw = "select username, email from registration where email = '$emailfetch' ";

$sql=mysql_query($sqlraw);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    if(isset($row['email'])){
      echo $row['username']; //shown only if post email exists in database
    }else{
    echo "Check Email Again";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

With these codes, I am getting username shown properly in div with id `display_info`. .

But I **want to use and set this username value** in my second **`udf1`** **input field**.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can't get clearly what you actually want. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I am getting username displayed in div with id display_info.. I want to display username in input field udf1 as value...

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
echo '<input type="text" name="user" value="' . $row['username'] . '">';
```

instaead of this

```
echo $row['username']; //shown only if post email exists in database
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#udf1').val(response);
```

after

```
$( '#display_info' ).html(response);
```

May be this can help.